# this is from a mouse motion tutorialTypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python

```
  File "C:\Users\amang\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\message que.py", line 16, in <module>
    event_text = event_text[- SCREEN_SIZE[1] /font_height:]
                 ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

i get this  error message when i run this line of code

```py
event_text = event_text[- SCREEN_SIZE[1] /font_height:]
```

any help would be greatfully appreciated

im running pycharm on a windows pc

i tried to correct the syntax error but im a newbie and confused

Comment: The problem is that `-SCREEN_SIZE[1]/font_height` is not an integer, thus the TypeError. It's impossible for us to help you unless you show us how you got those variables, so please post your full code so we can see what `SCREEN_SIZE` and `font_height` are.

Comment: Try `- SCREEN_SIZE[1] //font_height`, with the integer division (double slash), `//`. Perhaps you're using a tutorial that was written for Python 2.

Comment: What are the values for `SCREEN_SIZE[1]` and `font_height`? You could hard code these, along with a simple `event_text` to make something we can run. You could also `print(- SCREEN_SIZE[1] /font_height)` to see what value you are dealing with. Finally, you'll have to decide how to deal with rounding. Round down? Half round? Is [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) right for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your problem is you're using float division(/) instead of integer division(//).
try:

```
event_text = event_text[- SCREEN_SIZE[1] // font_height:]
```